# How to accurately get Y value from location manager heading

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to get the Y value from the location manager heading for the purpose of animating an image on the screen as you angle your phone up and down. I'm using the following CLLocationManager delegate method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
   print("Y: \(newHeading.y)")
}
```

When I have the phone in the normal position where it's standing upright, I'm seeing a Y value of about -45. However, when I angle the phone both up or down, I'm seeing the Y values start to near 0, regardless of whether I'm pointing the phone up or down. How can I determine the Y values accurately so as to differentiate between angling the device up and down?

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to use Core Motion, not Core Location. The accelerometer will let you figure out the way the device is oriented (which way is up)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was a way to use Core Location since I'm already using it for getting user's location, but I think you're right. Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Y values from accelerometer data. Unable to differentiate between pointing phone up and down since Y values are the same.

Comment: @codeman Add code to this question or a new one.